# FontSubstitutions: how do they work?

Tags: front-end, fonts

I'm puzzled by `FontSubstitutions`. The help says this:

> FontSubstitutions
>   is an option for Style and Cell that gives a list of substitutions to try for font family names.

I typed this:

```
Options[Style, FontSubstitutions]
```

with the result:

> Options::optnf: FontSubstitutions is not a known option for Style. >>

OK. So I try the example instead:

```
Options[$FrontEnd, FontSubstitutions]
```

and get a list of rules:

```
{FontSubstitutions -> {"Helv" -> "Helvetica", "Arial" -> "Helvetica",  
 "Times New Roman" -> "Times", "Courier New" -> "Courier",  
 "Lucidabright" -> "Times", "Charter" ->  "Helvetica", 
 "Lucidatypewriter" -> "Courier", "Fixed" -> "Monaco", 
 "AGaramond" -> "Times", "Avant Garde" -> "Helvetica", "Bodoni" -> "Times",
 "Bookman" -> "Times", "Caslon 3 Roman" -> "Times", ...
```

(Some of these rules are a bit strange - almost like misspellings...)

In the tutorial *tutorial/TextAndFontOptions*, I read:

> In addition, you can set FontSubstitutions to be a list of rules that give replacements to try for font family names.

So my interpretation of this is that, when you supply a string for `FontFamily`, *Mathematica* will, on failing to find any kind of matching font for that string, see if there's a rule for it, and then use the equivalent font given by that rule. However, I've not yet managed to make it happen.

Here I try Bodoni. It's not currently active (and the basic face is called Bodoni Book anyway), so it should be substituted by Times. But it appears as Lucida Grande.

```
Style["The quick brown fox", 60, FontFamily -> "Bodoni"]
```

[image: font substitutions]

and I couldn't get any of the rules to be applied.

I also tried setting a paragraph of text in a particular font (the terrible Dom Casual, which has a rule replacing it with Helvetica), then closing Mathematica, de-activating the font, then re-opening Mathematica and the document. The paragraph's font reverted to ... Lucida Grande.

So, does anyone know how `FontSubstitutions` works?

Comment: "so it should be substituted by Times" -- Why?  Did you add a rule to that effect?

Comment: it's further down the list of rules - there are 142 of them. I'll fiddle with the list a bit... :)

Comment: @cormullion You may find it easier to experiment with `FontSubstitutions` by using the selector syntax form for options like this: `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {FontSubstitutions, "Bodoni"}]` .  You can also use assign values by putting the `CurrentValue` expression on the left-hand side of an equal sign.

Comment: @cormullion And yes, I can reproduce your problem with the Mac v9 version (I think it works elsewhere).  It does look like `FontSubstitutions` is not working correctly on Mac.

Comment: Seems like it works as it should on Windows (9.0.1), except that the first time the substitution is employed, it gets "stuck"--subsequent changes to the `CurrentValue` have no effect. Must be cached somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Mathematica* version 10, this now works on Mac OS X.

For example, this rule is part of the system-supplied `FontSubstitutions` list:

```
"Meridien" -> "Times"
```

So when you type in the font name either incorrectly or if the system can't find a font with that name:

```
Style["The quick brown fox", 80, FontFamily -> "Meridien"]
```

you see the designated substitution:

[image: font substitution in action]

Then, if you activate the font, or type its name correctly:

```
Style["The quick brown fox", 80, FontFamily -> "Meridien LT Std Roman"]
```

you see the correct font:

[image: font substitution not required]

Thanks John Fultz!