# Setting OperatorSubstitution to False has issues with PDF and EPS exports. Are these bugs?

Tags: plotting, fonts

In `Plot`, I would like to use my own font, eg [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html), for operators such as ×, so I set `OperatorSubstitution` to `False` as follows.

```
Plot[
  x,
  {x, 0, 10^10},
  BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Inconsolata"}
]
```

There are three vector formats into which I can export the figure: SVG, EPS, and PDF. Only the SVG export gives the correct result, ie the character × is in the font specified. The others have the following issues. My first question is: **Are they bugs?**

- PDF export: operators are omitted altogether.
- EPS export: the instruction of setting `OperatorSubstitution` is omitted, ie font substitution for operators still occur.

I'm using Mathematica 9 for Mac.

My second question is: **Is there any way to work around the issue with PDF export?**

Comment: Could this be an issue with the font? I can't replicate the PDF export problem on Windows using Verdana, Consolas or Vivaldi: it definitely uses the selected font for operators and the custom Mathematica fonts are not used. And I have never had this problem on my Mac at home. I have Mathematica 9 on both machines. Maybe try Consolas for the time being?

Comment: Looks more like a Mac problem (for PDF at least). I can't get other fonts to display their own operators - looks like it defaults to something else.

Comment: With Consolas, again only SVG export works. PDF export gives a rectangle with a question mark in it for ×. If the issues are non-existent in Windows, then I guess it's a Mac-specific problem like cormullion suggested. That's sad. Why oh why...

Comment: There are some [similar problems](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18957/fontsubstitutions-how-do-they-work) that appear to be Mac-only...

Comment: After reading your and many other related topics I have an impression that the Mac version is inferior in terms of working with fonts. Apologies for venting my frustration here, but I'm disappointed in its typesetting capability in general, and the statement that [Mathematica has by far the world's most sophisticated and convenient mathematical typesetting technology](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html). (I pretty much love all else though!)

Comment: Well, I've seen many Windows and Linux font problems mentioned here, too, but perhaps the Mac users whine more... :)

Comment: Its important to understand in the eps/pdf cases, mathematica does not put the actual font in the file, just the font name. So what you see depends on your viewer finding the font on your system and how it handles an unknown font.

Comment: What does that mean in my case, in which the viewers are Adobe Reader 10.1.7 and Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, both Inconsolata and Consolas are installed in (ie not unknown to) my system, and basic characters are already in the font specified?

Comment: yea i think thats not the issue now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to george2079's answer, now I know what happens with EPS export in this case. The issue with PDF export might be related to this explanation.

`Export` (in Mathematica for Mac, at least the V9 that I'm using) **always** exports an EPS file in the [Mac OS Roman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) regardless of

- `$SystemCharacterEncoding`
- `ExternalDataCharacterEncoding` in the Global Preferences
- `CharacterEncoding` option of `Export`

(None of these is set to `MacintoshRoman` on my machine. Yet in the EPS file `MacintoshRomanEncoding` is present.)

This is particularly problematic for the particular example case brought up in this topic because [the multiplication sign is **not** in the Mac OS Roman character set (but present in ISO-8859-1)](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/charsetdiffs.html#d)! That's why Windows users don't have my problem.

In Fact, Mathematica **for Mac** does a **good** job here; it puts the correctness of the symbols in the top priority. If we have a look in the EPS source file of

```
Export["file.eps", Plot[
  x, {x, 0, 10^10},
  BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Inconsolata"}
]]
```

we can see that, even though `OperatatorSubstitution` has been set to `False`, Mathematica invokes the Mathematica1 font anyway when encountering a character (in this case, ×) which is not in the character set of the encoding (Mac OS Roman). For [Mathematica1 in any encoding](http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/tech/encodings/mathmat1.htm), × corresponds to the **octal** code `\264`. If we remove the line that specify the use of Mathematica1 (`9 /Mathematica1 Msf`), expectedly we get the Japanese currency sign (the actual character that `\264` corresponds to in the Mac OS Roman encoding).

In the first example from george2079, we can see that whatever the encoding the EPS file has been exported in, the octal code for × is `\264` because the universal Mathematica1 is being used. In the next example, Mathematica is told not to use Mathematica1. That octal code is then converted to `\327`, the × in the ISO-8859-1 (or compatible) encoding. This doesn't happen in my Mathematica for Mac, because there's no × code to convert to under the Mac OS Roman encoding (and Mathematica retains the line `9 /Mathematica1 Msf`).

What Mathematica for Mac does **bad** is the stubborn enforcement of Mac OS Roman.

There must really be some way to use other encodings in `Export` in Mathematica for Mac. It would be a bit ridiculous if there wasn't...

Answer (score 4):

comment w/code  In case this helps sort things out, taking the custom font out of the picture, compare

```
Export["file.eps",  Plot[x, {x, 0, 10^10}]
```

with :

```
Export["file.eps",  Plot[x, {x, 0, 10^10}, 
     BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}}]]
```

with windows in the eps file you can see the difference: "4 x" appears as

```
9 /Times-Roman-MISO Msf
0 9.264 m
(4) N
9 /Mathematica1 Msf
5.56 9.264 m
(\264) N
```

vs

```
9 /Times-Roman-MISO Msf
0 9.264 m
(4) N
5.56 9.264 m
(\327) N
```

Take a look at what your mac version is doing. And note you might have an issue if your custom font doesn't have the  \327 character defined which is "ISO latin" x

Comment: Thank you. This really helps me investigate the problem!